# Append string to the 2nd column if a condition is satisfied, using sed

Tags: text-processing, csv

CSV file:

```
A,12345,hello
B,67890,hi
A,123456,yo
```

Expected output: Should add two zeros at the end of the 2nd column if the 1st column is `A`:

```
A,1234500,hello
B,67890,hi
A,12345600,yo
```

Comment: Is this homework? Where are you getting stuck on the assignment? Since you say in the Subject that you have to do it with `sed` (which is not the best choice for this), why not tag it with `sed`?

Answer (score 7):

If your data is a generic CSV file that may contain fields with embedded commas, quotes, and newlines, then we need to use a CSV-aware tool like [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to do the transformation:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put -S '$1 == "A" { $2 .= "00" }' file
A,1234500,hello
B,67890,hi
A,12345600,yo
```

This reads your data as header-less CSV records and adds `00` to the end of the value of the 2nd field if the 1st field's value is `A`.  The `-S` option to the `put` sub-command makes Miller treat all records as strings, regardless of whether they are numbers or strings.

Miller can do in-place editing using its `-I` option.

---

If your data is in a header-less *simple* CSV format, meaning it contains no fields with embedded commas, quotes, or newlines (things that require special quoting in CSV), you may use `awk` to do the transformation:

```bash
$ awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 == "A" { $2 = $2 "00" }; 1' file
A,1234500,hello
B,67890,hi
A,12345600,yo
```

Here, comma-delimited fields are read by `awk`; if the 1st field is `A`, the string `00` is added to the 2nd field.  The trailing lone `1` makes `awk` output the (possibly modified) record.

---

`sed` doesn't really lend itself to editing structured documents in convenient or easily maintainable ways.  If your data is in a header-less *simple* CSV form, you could probably get away by matching lines that start with the string `A,`, and insert two zeros before the 2nd occurrence of a comma on those lines:

```bash
$ sed '/^A,/ s/,/00,/2' file
A,1234500,hello
B,67890,hi
A,12345600,yo
```

... but note that `sed` has no notion of records or fields and treats each input line as a generic text string.

In the `sed` expression above, `/^A,/` is the *address* used by the subsequent substitution command, meaning the `s` command will be applied to all lines matching that regular expression (lines beginning with the string `A,`).  The substitution matches the *second* comma on the line due to the `2` at the end of the expression and replaces this with the string `00,`.

The equivalent editing command in the `ed` editor would have been `g/^A,/ s/,/00,/2` ("apply the following substitution to all lines matching this regular expression"). This would have worked in `vi` too, had it understood the `2` at the end of the expression (which it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my @a = .split(",");  \
             if @a[0] eq "A" {@a.[1] ~= "00"};  \
             .put for @a.join(",");'   file
```

The above code should only be used on *simple*-CSV, that is, without special characters that require escaping/quoting (e.g. embedded commas, embedded doublequotes, embedded newlines). Basically for `-ne` each line, you:

1. *`split` on `,` commas,*
2. *run a conditional that concatenates `00` to the end of the `[1]` second element if the `[0]` first element is string `eq`ual to "A", then*
3. *out`put` the elements `join`ed back together on commas.*

Sample Input:

```
A,12345,hello
B,67890,hi
A,123456,yo
```

Sample Output:

```
A,1234500,hello
B,67890,hi
A,12345600,yo
```

If you have more complicated CSV, or you simply want a more robust solution, use Raku's `Text::CSV` module:

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv( in => $*IN, sep => ",");  \
         for @a -> $a {$a.[1] ~= "00"  if  $a.[0] eq "A"};  \
         csv( in => @a, out => $*OUT);'  file
```

You can change the separator `sep => ","` to whatever suits your input file, e.g. `\t` for a TSV file. Sample Output same as above.

https://raku.land/github:Tux/Text::CSV
https://raku.org